# TypeError: memorySession is not a function with Telegraf

Tags: node.js, bots, telegraf

I need use a "memory session" in my Telegraf bot like this : `bot.use(Telegraf.memorySession())`, but I am getting the following error `TypeError: memorySession is not a function`. Have you any ideas to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`Telegraf.session()`](https://telegraf.js.org/modules.html#session) - if some resource or guide tells you to use `memorySession()`, it's possible that it was written for an older version of `Telegraf`.

Comment: I'm using it with the i18n-telegraf package (for remembering the user's language)

Comment: Yes, the example there in the README appear to be 2 years old. Try `Telegraf.session()` instead.